# Underfitting a single batch: Can't cause autoencoder to overfit multi-sample batches of 1d data. How to debug?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

### **TL;DR**

I am unable to overfit batches with multiple samples using autoencoder.

Fully connected decoder seems to handle more samples per batch than conv decoder, but then also fails when number of samples increases.
**Why is this happening, and how to debug this?**

---

### In depth

I am trying to use an auto encoder on 1d data points of size `(n, 1, 1024)`, where `n` is the number of samples in the batch.

I am trying to overfit to that single batch.

Using a convolutional decoder, I am only able to fit a single sample (`n=1`), and when `n>1` I am unable to drop the loss (MSE) below 0.2.

**In blue: expected output (=input), in orange: reconstruction.**

Single sample, single batch:
[image: Conv1sample]

Multiple samples, single batch, loss won't go down:
[image: Conv4samples]

Using more than one sample, we can see the net learns the general shape of the input (=output) signal, but greatly misses the bias.

---

Using a fully connected decoder does manage to reconstruct batches of multiple samples:

[image: Fc4samples]

---

### Relevant code:

```
class Conv1DBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size):
        super().__init__()
        self._in_channels = in_channels
        self._out_channels = out_channels
        self._kernel_size = kernel_size

        self._block = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv1d(
                        in_channels=self._in_channels,
                        out_channels=self._out_channels,
                        kernel_size=self._kernel_size,
                        stride=1,
                        padding=(self._kernel_size - 1) // 2,
                ),
                # nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=out_channels),
                nn.ReLU(True),
                nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        for layer in self._block:
            x = layer(x)
        return x


class Upsample1DBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, factor):
        super().__init__()
        self._in_channels = in_channels
        self._out_channels = out_channels
        self._factor = factor

        self._block = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv1d(
                        in_channels=self._in_channels,
                        out_channels=self._out_channels,
                        kernel_size=3,
                        stride=1,
                        padding=1
                ),  # 'same'
                nn.ReLU(True),
                nn.Upsample(scale_factor=self._factor, mode='linear', align_corners=True),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x_tag = x
        for layer in self._block:
            x_tag = layer(x_tag)
        # interpolated = F.interpolate(x, scale_factor=0.5, mode='linear') # resnet idea
        return x_tag
```

encoder:

```
self._encoder = nn.Sequential(
            # n, 1024
            nn.Unflatten(dim=1, unflattened_size=(1, 1024)),
            # n, 1, 1024
            Conv1DBlock(in_channels=1, out_channels=8, kernel_size=15),
            # n, 8, 512
            Conv1DBlock(in_channels=8, out_channels=16, kernel_size=11),
            # n, 16, 256
            Conv1DBlock(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=7),
            # n, 32, 128
            Conv1DBlock(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5),
            # n, 64, 64
            Conv1DBlock(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3),
            # n, 128, 32
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=128, out_channels=128, kernel_size=32, stride=1, padding=0),  # FC
            # n, 128, 1
            nn.Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1),
            # n, 128
        )
```

conv decoder:

```
self._decoder = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Unflatten(dim=1, unflattened_size=(128, 1)),  # 1
    Upsample1DBlock(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, factor=4),  # 4
    Upsample1DBlock(in_channels=64, out_channels=32, factor=4),  # 16
    Upsample1DBlock(in_channels=32, out_channels=16, factor=4),  # 64
    Upsample1DBlock(in_channels=16, out_channels=8, factor=4),  # 256
    Upsample1DBlock(in_channels=8, out_channels=1, factor=4),  # 1024
    nn.ReLU(True),
    nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(True),
    nn.Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1),
    nn.Linear(1024, 1024)
)
```

FC decoder:

```
self._decoder = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(128, 256),
    nn.ReLU(True),
    nn.Linear(256, 512),
    nn.ReLU(True),
    nn.Linear(512, 1024),
    nn.ReLU(True),
    nn.Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1),
    nn.Linear(1024, 1024)
)
```

---

Another observation is that when the batch size increases more, to say, 16, the FC decoder also starts to fail.

In the image, 4 samples of a 16 sample batch I am trying to overfit

[image: fc16Samples]

---

What could be wrong with the conv decoder?

How to debug this or make the conv decoder work?

Comment: I think the training code is also relevant to the issue. Please do add it to the question.

Comment: @akshayk07 I will add it. Meanwhile, I will note that the exact same training code and infrastructure is used for training for MNIST and works both for overfirring and generalization, so I doubt it is bugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Dying ReLU](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/what-is-the-dying-relu-problem-in-neural-networks)

- I think the main reason for **underfitting** in your case is [**Dying Relu**](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/what-is-the-dying-relu-problem-in-neural-networks) problem. Your network is simple Autoencoder with [**no skip/residual**](https://theaisummer.com/skip-connections/) connections. So **Code** in the bottleneck should encode enough information about **bias** in the data to make **Decoder** to learn.
- So if **ReLU** activation function is used **Negative Biased** data information can be **lost** due to Dying ReLU problem. The solution is to to use better activation functions like **LeakyReLU**, **ELU**, [**MISH**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.08681), etc.

### Linear vs Conv.

In your case, you are **overfitting** on a single batch. As **Linear** layers will have more **parameters** than that of **Convolution** layers maybe they are **Memorising** given small data easily.

### Batch Size

As you are **overfitting** on a single batch, a **small-batch** of data will make it very easy to **memorise** on the other hand for **large batch** with single **Update** of network per batch(during overfitting) make network to learn **Generalized** abstract features. (This works better if more batches are there with a lot of variety of data)

I tried to reproduce your problem using simple **Gaussian** data. Just by using **LeakyReLU** in place of **ReLU** with proper learning rate solved the problem.
Same architecture given by you is used.

Hyper parameters:

batch_size = 16

epochs = 100

lr = 1e-3

optimizer = Adam

loss(after training with **ReLU**) = 0.27265918254852295

loss(after training with **LeakyReLU**) = 0.0004763789474964142

### With Relu

[image: with relu]

### With Leaky Relu

[image: with Leaky relu]

Comment: **The dying relu was indeed the major problem.** However, the net was not deep enough for residual connections to solve vanishing gradients, as this wasn't the problem. The secondary problem was really lack of channels in the early layers of the encoder. adding channels allowed for nice convergence.